# Why nginx ignores root and location directives?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm running Nginx as a service in docker-compose, with a volume mounted at /app inside the container.

I just copied the whole project structure from Linux to MacOS where it worked fine.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
            - ./app:/app

    sass:
        image: larryprice/sass
        volumes:
            - ./app/public/assets:/src

    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/php/PHP.Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
```

I have a simple configuration for a PHP app, but the root directive inside location seems to be ignored. I can't understand why.

This single configuration file in conf.d directory:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /app/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;     
    }
}
```

When trying to access `http://localhost/index.php` it fails with

```
172.19.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2021:11:22:28 +0000] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36" "-"
2021/10/16 11:22:28 [error] 26#26: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

So, it defaults to looking in `/usr/share/nginx/html/`, but there is matching `location` for a uri.

Can anyone explain this?
Many thanks!

Comment: That isn't the `server` block that is handling the request. There must be another `server` block defined in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.

Comment: @RichardSmith, there is no `server` block in my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file, but i have `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` inside http block in this file.

Comment: can you mount the nginx.conf file to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` instead? its probably because the master file has the root directory already configured there so you need to overwrite it or replace it like I'm suggesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project structure is from this resource: https://www.sitepoint.com/docker-php-development-environment/

Instead of just copying project structure from Linux (as I mentioned in a question) I sequentially followed this tutorial manually adding those directives and surprisingly it started to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Settings in `fastcgi_params` may overwrite your `SCRIPT_FILENAME` param, you could try to move `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` after `include fastcgi_params`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /app/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```